# Utilizar api con credenciales para hacer login desde mi pagina web

Tags: php, api

como puedo hacer un login.php desde mi pagina web para enviar a los usuarios a un portal externo a través de una api. Los requerimientos es enviar un xml o json con la estrutura siguiente:

```
<Login>
  <APIUsername></APIUsername>
  <APIPassword></APIUPassword>
  <Email></Email>
  <ContractNumber></ContractNumber>
</Login>
```

El portal externo me debe devolver un LoginToken si el usuario esta dado de alta con ellos.
Ya tengo las url de la api y las credenciales.

Comment: Hola buenos días si tienes algo desarrollado por favor colócalo para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Todavía no tengo nada estructurado, únicamente me pasaron las credenciales de la api y la url y debo conectarme al portal de ellos. Tengo conocimiento en programación phpy mysql pero nunca había tratado con una api.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes mostrar parte del código que tienes.
En caso contrario prueba a utilizar $_POST/$_GET para tu envió de datos o $_REQUEST para recibir las "credenciales" que necesitas de la API. Aquí la documentación oficial [Variables desde fuentes externas](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.external.php) de PHP.
Tambien prueba replantear la pregunta con más información.